# Can we import an Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio and does it support SVN?

Tags: android, android-studio

I did not try Android Studio yet ( Dowloading it as of now), just curious, is there a way to import the projects from Eclipse over ? Does it have SVN plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the developers blog they say it's possible: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html
I couldn't make the Studio run so far.

Comment: i have it running in windows 7 now. What OS are you trying it on ?

Comment: @Rotem, you might want to try this link for your issue. http://www.ootpapps.com/2013/05/android-studio-wont-open-how-to-fix-android-studio/

Comment: It could be just the JDK_HOME. I had that set in my environment and I did not have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

yes its supported in Android Studio.

refer this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html